# Psalm stopped seeing errors

Tags: php, psalm-php

I'm here with the one of the weirdest questions in my life. Suddenly psalm stopped seeing any errors in my code. I was fixing some issues, and then all of a sudden I stopped getting errors from psalm. I know there are many of them, because I used to ignore some of them within `psalm.xml`. Now I rolled back to master (stable code), and removed all exceptions from the config. Still nothing.

**psalm.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<psalm
    errorLevel="1"
    resolveFromConfigFile="true"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="https://getpsalm.org/schema/config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://getpsalm.org/schema/config vendor/vimeo/psalm/config.xsd"
>
    <projectFiles>
        <directory name="src/" />
        <ignoreFiles>
            <directory name="vendor" />
        </ignoreFiles>
    </projectFiles>
    <issueHandlers>
        <MixedPropertyTypeCoercion>
            <errorLevel type="suppress">
                <file name="src/Transport/Message/Params/SendMessageParams.php"/>
            </errorLevel>
        </MixedPropertyTypeCoercion>
    </issueHandlers>
    <stubs><file name="./config/bootstrap.php" /></stubs>
</psalm>
```

Note, I removed about 20 entries from `issueHandlers` which would trigger errors (just to test if psalm working).

**Command:**
`sudo -u wwwbm -E -H /usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=2048M vendor/bin/psalm`

**Output:**

```
Scanning files...
Analyzing files...

░
------------------------------
No errors found!
------------------------------

Checks took 2.14 seconds and used 217.018MB of memory
Psalm was unable to infer types in the codebase
```

I'm stuck. I'm not even sure at which moment it stopped showing errors, just in the middle of coding actually.

I know the question is too broad now, so I'll try to make it a little bit more strict:

Is there any way to debug psalm? Any kind of verbose mode, or maybe any internal debugging system exists for the lib? I'm literally going crazy.

**Psalm version:** 3.18.2

Comment: are there any other psalm specific files in your projectdirs ? (such things can be in .gitignore which could explain why your rollback had no effect). If you use psalm from your IDE then i'd also have a peek in your IDE's configfile (settings.json for VS code for example). I can imagine accidentally hitting some keybind (or misclicking) and triggering an 'ignore all these errors'-type-a-scenario. Pure speculation of course, but maybe you hadn't thought of it yet, it's worth seeing whats in there.

Comment: There are `--debug` and `--debug-by-line` switches that may provide you with some insight.

Comment: But also your Psalm version is really, really old.

Comment: @weirdan agreed. I just updated to 4.x and it works now without any code changes. Still don't know what was it.